# Animate a TextView to slide off the screen

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

I'm animating a TextView with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

and doing this:

```
textView.startAnimation(slideOutAnim);
```

But this code only makes the TextView animate about 1/4 of the screen length. What should I set the toYDelta to so that it ensures that the TextView is out of the screen? I know I could just set it to a really high number but is there a more efficient/effective way to get this done? Thanks

Comment: textView animate relative to itself , you should set relative to it's parent,then it go out of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your animation to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
       android:duration="1000"
       android:toYDelta="100%p"<!--relative to parent-->
       android:fromYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

note that this work if it's parent have full screen height, actually it animate to 100% of height of it's parent